# Strange Bug in iOS 6 UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem, titleview

I have found a strange bug in ios. When I use UINavigationController and push other controllers, the titleView shifted to the right so much as how many controllers was pushed

It's looks like this:

[image]

My code is simple:

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"Test Title";
```

In the second case, controller has 5th in `viewControllers` stack. The controller in the all cases is same.

I was using the `appearance` for `UIBarButtonItem`, in my AppDelegate.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-1000, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: When text is long enough(but in frame) it happens 100%.

Comment: How do you realize your (custom?) back button? Could it be that that one grows in size for each nested view controller?

Comment: Yes. This is my bad. The backButton title is too long, that's why. But I can't understand, look at my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fix it with some trick =)

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:0.1]}
                                                                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```